# Django + Postgres: A string literal cannot contain NUL (0x00) characters

Tags: python, django, postgresql

I'm syncing a large amount of data and I'm getting this error back: `A string literal cannot contain NUL (0x00) characters.` Obviously this is a postgres problem, but I'm not quite sure how to solve it. Is there a way to strip null characters out at the Django model level? I have a large set of fields that I'm syncing.

Comment: Most strings are terminated with a `NUL` character. What exactly are you trying to store in the database? If you want to store binary data, you should store this in a `BinaryField`: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#binaryfield

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem it's just text. they're fields from a website like "title" and "body".

Comment: I think you should inspect the text you are trying to store in the database, likely there is an encoding issue with your scraper (?).

Answer (score 27):

[This bug fix](https://github.com/cms-dev/cms/issues/888) suggests:

```
s.decode("utf-8", errors="replace").replace("\x00", "\uFFFD")
```

Only the `.replace` is necessary for the OP's issue, which replaces the null with a � character. I've included `.decode` too as it protects against other encoding issues that might arise in similar situations.

This would go in a `.clean` method somewhere - maybe subclass TextField or CharField if you want to apply it globally.

Answer (score 2):

Unless you definitely do want to store NUL characters, you should sanitize your text  so it does not contain them. At the model level, you'd define a `clean_fieldname` method to do that.

If you do want to store them, you need to store them in a binary-compatible field in the database. Django 1.6+ has `BinaryField` which should work.