# Django + Postgres: saving PDF file with NUL (0x00) characters to DB and decoding it back to PDF

Tags: python, django, postgresql, pdf

I have a pdf file that I want to save in my Postgres DB 
[image: PDF file]

When I tried to save the file it brings `A string literal cannot contain NUL (0x00) characters.` so I followed the solution from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57371164/django-postgres-a-string-literal-cannot-contain-nul-0x00-characters) which replaces the null with a � character 
`unicode(ppbData[0], errors='ignore').replace("\x00", "\uFFFD")`

The problem is that I can't convert it back to PDF now. I tried `encode()` and other methods

```
file = open('new.pdf', 'wb')
file.write(text.encode())
file.close()
```

but it returns blank pdf 
[image: Blank PDF file]

Is there any way to replaces the � character with a null or any other way to convert it back to normal pdf? Maybe the first solution with replacing also wasn't right and there is another way?

Comment: The problem is that `\uFFFD` is also composed of valid binary bytes and could already be occurring in your PDF, thus when you convert back it _over-converts_ bytes that you never encoded to begin with.  You can use a different encoding -- [base64.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/base64.html) .  `base64.encode(file.read())`

Comment: Later decode with `base64.b64decode` or equivalent in javascript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Django model class has a FileField which stores the filename in the database.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/files/#using-files-in-models

The actual file contents are stored via settings.DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE, which is normally on the filesystem.
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/topics/files/#file-storage

However, cloud storage can also be used:

- https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html
- https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2017/08/01/how-to-setup-amazon-s3-in-a-django-project.html

If you really want to store the file in the database, you can either base64 encode it (as [Ross Rogers](https://stackoverflow.com/users/20712/ross-rogers) mentioned) or you can use a [BinaryField](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#binaryfield).